# Get the previous not null value if the current value is null - Azure databricks

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a table which has the below values

```
ID   Date        FinalDate
1    20120101     NULL
1    20120201     20120201
1    20120301     NULL
1    20120401     20120401
1    20120501     NULL
1    20120601     NULL
```

I am looking to have the output table display this

```
ID   Date        FinalDate
1    20120101     NULL
1    20120201     20120201
1    20120301     20120201
1    20120401     20120401
1    20120501     20120401
1    20120601     20120401
```

After the first not null value any null values should pick up the previous not null value. This example only has 1 ID but i have multiple ID's with the same scenario.

Can someone please provide me with any help on how to write a code in sql,python or pyspark to achieve this on databricks. I am new to this so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code to get your desired output -

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

df.withColumn("FinalDate", func.last('FinalDate', True).over(Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('Date'))).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried an example using pyspark:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
data = [
    (1, 20120101, None),
    (1, 20120201, 20120201),
    (1, 20120301, None),
    (1, 20120401, 20120401),
    (1, 20120501, None),
    (1, 20120601, None),
    (2, 20120101, None),
    (2, 20120201, 20120201),
    (2, 20120301, None),
    (2, 20120401, 20120401),
    (2, 20120501, None),
    (2, 20120601, None)
]
schema = ["ID", "Date", "FinalDate"]
Dilip_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)
window_spec = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("Date")
result_df = Dilip_df.withColumn(
    "FinalDate",
    F.coalesce("FinalDate", F.last("FinalDate", True).over(window_spec))
)
result_df.show()
```

**Result:**

```
+---+--------+---------+
| ID|    Date|FinalDate|
+---+--------+---------+
|  1|20120101|     NULL|
|  1|20120201| 20120201|
|  1|20120301| 20120201|
|  1|20120401| 20120401|
|  1|20120501| 20120401|
|  1|20120601| 20120401|
|  2|20120101|     NULL|
|  2|20120201| 20120201|
|  2|20120301| 20120201|
|  2|20120401| 20120401|
|  2|20120501| 20120401|
|  2|20120601| 20120401|
+---+--------+---------+
```

- The above code uses the coalesce function along with the last window function to fill the null values in the "**FinalDate**" column with the last non-null value within the same "**ID**" partition.
- A window specification `(window_spec)` is defined to partition the data by "**ID**" and order it by "**Date**.
- The withColumn method is used to create a new column "**FinalDate**,"where null values are replaced with the last non-null value within the same "**ID**" partition.
- This is achieved using the coalesce function along with the last
  window function and the specified window specification.